# Preloading a UICollectionView in a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am using `UICollectionView` inside a `UIPageViewController`.
Each page is an instance of the same subclass of `UICollectionViewController`.
Whenever I do a page swipe to see a page I haven't seen before, the animation gets a small delay (few milliseconds) to start because of the time `UICollectionView` takes to go through all the delegate/datasource methods.
So I was trying to implement a pre-caching system to load the viewcontroller before the user actually starts swiping.
I am able to create it easily, but, for some reason, whenever I call `reloadData` on the non-visible `ViewController`, none of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate methods get called.
So far I have tried to use: `setNeedsDisplay`, `setNeedsLayout`, `setLayoutIfNeeded` and `invalidateLayout` to force them to get called, but nothing is working.
The `viewcontroller` is not `nil`.  The `view` is not `nil`.
Does anyone know what could be the reason? Is it because the viewcontroller is not in the viewport?

Comment: Agree with Antzi Answer , you should pre-cached the data only not UI.

Comment: If the major bottleneck `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` and all of the calculations therein are based on your model, can you not just do those calculations as soon as your model becomes available and pass those values in an array?

Comment: I tried this solution, but it looks it still not enough to avoid the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the view controller first is probably not the best idea.

You should rather cache the data source.

About reloadData not working properly with a non displayed controller, you are right, it's because the controller is not present.

Comment: The major bottleneck is `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. This method gets called for all the cells (even those not visible) and is a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method.

Comment: Can you tell us about what is in your cell ?

Comment: Text and images. So the height of each cell is variable.

Comment: I don't think any caching would help you with this one, since sizeForItemAtIndexPath will be called everytime a new cell appear.
How is the image loaded and how much does it weight ?

Comment: The problem is not in the image, I am lazy loading it, so it's not affecting the time taken from `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. Also `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is called for *all* the cells, despite them being visible or not. Once the `UICollectionViewController` appears, the cells get cached (I think through the `UICollectionReusableView` system) so `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` doesn't get called anymore.

Comment: What you can try is defer loading the cells to after viewWill/DidAppear. 
This should the page prevent the transition from stuttering, but still load fast enough so that the user doesn't notice views where missing.
A simple way to do it is return no elements until viewWill/DidAppear is called.

Answer (score 0):

The delegates won't fire unless the view is visible.To counter the delay you are facing you would have to ditch the collectionview and use collectionview controller and add those collectionview controllers as child to page controller

Note: Set the frame appropriately for each collection controller

```
CollectionController *collectionController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Calculate"];
        [self addChildViewController:collectionController];
        collectionController.view.frame = self.calculationView.bounds;
        [self.pageControllerView addSubview:collectionController.view];
        [collectionController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```